# Restriction of an ideal is an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

Given the following localization of ring:
$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}:m,n \in \mathbb{Z} ; p \nmid n\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.
We look at an Ideal $I\subset \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and take its restriction $I'=I\cap \mathbb{Z}$. Why can we say that this is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$?

I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain and that there exist a homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. But still I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: Well, (i) is it a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$? and (ii) Is it closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{Z}$? P.S. It has nothing to do with $\mathbb{Z}$ being a PID. Just identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with its image in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, since the canonical map $m\longmapsto \frac{m}{1}$ is one-to-one.

Comment: When $I$ is a  subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, is it then necessarily a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$? Why?

Comment: You are **not** trying to prove that $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, so why are you checking on $I$?

Comment: But why then $I'=I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ should be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$? Is it simply because of the ideal properties of $I\cap \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Who is $A$? And, last time I checked, (i) ideals are subgroups; (ii) subrings are subgroups; and (iii) intersection of subgroups is a subgroup. Did that change recently?

Comment: sorry for the error. Ok , now I get it. $I'$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, because $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $I$ forms also an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and in $\mathbb{Z}$.(subgroups of ideals are ideals)

Comment: No, subgroups of ideals need not be ideals. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ideal of itself, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: ok, last try:(i) $I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of  $ \mathbb{Z}$ and  (ii) $ I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication because of $ \mathbb{Z}$. so $I'$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I don't know what "because of $\mathbb{Z}$" means, but I'm pretty sure that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily check the definition directly; if $I$ is closed under addition and under multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$, then $I\cap\Bbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and under multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}$.

Alternatively, you could note that $I\cap\Bbb{Z}$ is the kernel of the restriction of the quotient map $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}_{(p)}/I$ to the subring $\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$.